# React does not display time only {"${new Date().getHours()}:${new Date().getMinutes()}"}

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React from a Udemy course and got stuck with this code. The exact same code seems to work on the video but does not display the time on my webpage only the actual code {"${new Date().getHours()}:${new Date().getMinutes()}"}. Please advise how I can get it to display the time.

My code:

```
 <div className={classes.FeatureData}>

       <p>{"${new Date().getHours()}:${new Date().getMinutes()}"} </p>

   </div>
```

Comment: what is the problem exactly? what does it display?

Comment: What was the output in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the " when you should use backstick:

Change (") by (`)

It must be like this:

{`${new Date().getHours()}:${new Date().getMinutes()}`}

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help I did try saving as single quotes but Visual Studio Code editor kept changing it to double quotes. I figured out how to change the quote preference setting and it works now.

Comment: Because it's not single quote but backstick, is not the same character. This is a single quote: ' and this is a backstick: `

Answer (score 0):

You need to use template strings:

```js
<div>
  <p>{`${new Date().getHours()}:${new Date().getMinutes()}`}</p>
</div>
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals